# VirtualHost not working for ".com" domain in localhost WAMP Server

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, virtualhost

Not sure if this is an issue with WAMP or Windows but here's what I've been trying to figure out for the past few hours.

I created a project and wanted to give it an alias that's easy for me to work with and it works with any other top-level domain such as ".org", ".gov", ".test" except ".com" and I don't really understand why.

Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/path-to-website"
  <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/path-to-website/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Details:
WAMP version: 3.2.0
PHP: 7.4
Apache: 2.4.2

Comment: You haven't really told us what the "issue" is so it's hard to know where it goes south or how to fix it. "not working" is not an acceptable description since it doesn't tell us anything about the issue. Did you restart Apache after editing the vhost? Did you also add `example.com` to your [hosts-file](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file-in-windows-10-and-why-you-might-want-to) and set it to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Also, you can remove the `ServerAlias`. That's used if you want to allow other (different) domains as well.

Comment: I'm getting a "This site can’t be reached" error in the browser. However, I'm not getting this when I try it with any other domain.

Comment: It helps if you answer the other questions I asked as well.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I added it my hosts-file and set it to `localhost` and tried setting it to `127.0.0.1` as well and it still isn't working. Got any suggestions?